# Network is unreachable : Wifi has no inet addr

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have this computer that does not connect to internet, Ubuntu 16.04 and I have no physical entry for an Ethernet connection. It only works on WiFi. This problem started when I switched network (I went to my friend place).

First, network-manager GUI desktop icon tells me that the connection has been successfully established (the logo on top right of the screen showing wifi signals).

I have 6 interfaces, two are bridges for vms, one is for docker, one local, one enp and one wifi. Sorry I can't copy-paste, no internet.

Important point to note, wifi interface has no inet addr (I'll get to that with dhclient later on)

From there, `ping google.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8` give `connect: Network is unreachable`.

Then, doing `route -n` gives me weird stuff :

1. WiFi interface `wlp4s0` does not show up
2. Each line has 0.0.0.0 has their gateway
3. There is no G flag (which mean no default gateway)

So I tried to default one using `sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1` and I get `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`.

I thought all this was from the DHCP client not setting an address IP so I tried `sudo rm /var/lib/dhcp/*.leases` and `sudo killall dhclient` and then `sudo dhclient wlp4s0`. The later hung. Nothing changed. I restarted my laptop.

As for logs, syslog keeps throwing DHCPREQUEST, then DHCPOFFER followed by DHCPNAK.

I did flush my ip table using `iptables -F`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok wow, hardware problem from the router, it could not send me a DHCP lease.

I tried reaching the gateway with an other connected computer on 192.168.1.1 and it gave us a blank page with a "Out of Memory" error.

Resetting the router for now has done the job.